# Convert currency to decimal in VB.NET

Tags: vb.net

I need to convert text in currency format to decimal format.

Example: US$12,500.50 -> 12500.50

That text is into a textbox. I used the formatCurrency() function, but I need to get the original text (decimal format).

How can I do this?

Comment: Are you saying you need help parsing a decimal from a string that always starts with "US$"?

Comment: That is exactly what I'm saying. Can you help me?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know for sure about this, but you can give it a try:

```
Dim NewString As String = Replace(Replace(TextBox1.Text, "US$", ""), ",", "")
Dim Currency As Decimal = CDec(NewString)

'Just to check if it works.
MessageBox.Show(Currency)
```

Answer (score 0):

For a start, don't use `FormatCurrency`.  Call `ToString` and pass "c" as the format specifier.  The inverse operation would be to call `Decimal.Parse` or `Decimal.TryParse` and specify currency formatting.

Comment: There's no need to say "thank you" and it is actually discouraged.  Comments should be kept to only what adds to the aim of answering the question.  What you should do though is to accept an answer if it does indeed answer your question so others can see that it is useful.

Answer (score 0):

Use NumberStyles

```
    Dim test As String = "US$12,500.50"
    Dim testAsNum As Decimal

    Dim ci As New Globalization.CultureInfo(Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.LCID)
    ci.NumberFormat.CurrencySymbol = "US$"

    Dim ns As Globalization.NumberStyles = Globalization.NumberStyles.AllowCurrencySymbol Or _
        Globalization.NumberStyles.AllowDecimalPoint Or _
        Globalization.NumberStyles.AllowThousands

    If Decimal.TryParse(test, ns, ci, testAsNum) Then
        Stop
    Else
        Stop
    End If
```