# How to convert currency to Decimal vb.net?

Tags: vb.net, currency

I have remote data that I have to display the total cost of two items.
Here is a sample I created to troubleshoot how to do the conversion to add the two items:

```
Dim test1 As String = "ZAR897.83"
Dim test2 As String = "ZAR900.83"
Dim t1 As Double = Val(test1)
Dim t2 As Double = Val(test2)
Dim TotalPrice As Decimal = 0.00
TotalPrice += CDec(t1)
TotalPrice += CDec(t2)
```

In the code above t1 resulted value is 0.0 and it is the same for t2.

Any help to add these values will be appreciated.

**Edit:** This question has been asked and was unanswered here: [Convert currency to decimal in VB.NET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24295825/convert-currency-to-decimal-vb-net)

**Edit:** I did not show all the different castings I tried because all the castings I tried gave build errors (which I assumed to be pointless to show because they were in a sense more incorrect). The reason why I got errors no matter how I tried to cast the numbers was due to my visual studio expect a comma instead of a period for decimal values and this was due to region settings in windows set up incorrectly.

Comment: Try `Decimal.Parse(t1, NumberStyles.Currency)`.

Comment: @VisualVincent "Overload resolution failed because no accessible 'Parse' can be called with these areguments:" it continues from there with extra text.

Comment: If "ZAR" is supposed to be South African Rand then no, you are not going to get that from Val() or Decimal.Parse().  .NET will only accept "897.83R".  It is up to you to remove ZAR from the string first.

Comment: This behaviour should not come as a surprise. If you read the docs (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k7beh1x9(v=vs.90).aspx) it clearly states "The Val function stops reading the string at the first character it cannot recognize as part of a number"

Comment: @HansPassant why the downvote? If the question was lacking quality please suggest an edit.

Comment: @MattWilko I assumed the behavior did exactly as it intended. The idea of showing this code was to assist with answers so everyone has an idea what I am attempting.

Comment: It was not my vote.  I can easily prove it by voting.  Here.

Comment: My downvote is because this question does not show any research effort.

Comment: @HansPassant sorry my mistake.

Comment: @Mattwilko thanks for feedback could you provide a link where I can read up on the conversion of currencies to any number format?

Comment: Is the currency always three characters at the start?

Comment: @AndrewMorton I am not sure if it will be always in the same currency. Etor gave a solution that parses the entire string for the number and return what I need without worrying about currency changes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Maybe you want something like that

```
Imports System

Public Class Program
    Private Shared Function GetCurrencyValue(input As String) As Double
        Dim s As String = ""
        For i As Integer = 0 To input.Length - 1
            If Char.IsNumber(input(i)) OrElse input(i) = "."C OrElse input(i) = "-"C Then
                s += input(i)
            End If
        Next
        Return Double.Parse(s)
    End Function

Public Shared Sub Main()
    Dim test1 As String = "ZAR897.83"
    Dim test2 As String = "ZAR900.83"

    Dim d1 As Double = GetCurrencyValue(test1)
    Dim d2 As Double = GetCurrencyValue(test2)

    Dim TotalPrice As Decimal = 0.00D

    TotalPrice += CDec(d1)
    TotalPrice += CDec(d2)

    Console.WriteLine(TotalPrice)
End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: "Input string was not in a correct format" in line 3. I also want to make sure that this works on any currency thus substring is a personal issue regardless.

Comment: Thanks, I used your code and the function returned the number as I needed. It also gave an error but I should be able to solve the issue.

Comment: You also will want to check for `"-"` char in your function

Answer (score 0):

I think this would help

`To Call this function use 
 Dim ListOfPrices As String() = {"ZAR897.83", "ZAR900.83"}
        Dim ReturnedPrice = ReturnVal(ListOfPrices)`

```
Function ReturnVal(ListOfPrices As String())
    Dim TotalPriceInStringFormat As String = "" 
    Dim myStringVal As String = ""
    Dim TotalPrice As Decimal = 0.0
    Dim MyBool As Boolean = False
    Dim count As Int16 = 0
    For Each priceInStrFormat As String In ListOfPrices
        TotalPriceInStringFormat = ""
        For Each c As Char In priceInStrFormat
            'If Char is Number or Period then append it
            If (Char.IsNumber(c) Or c = ".") Then
                TotalPriceInStringFormat += c
            ElseIf (Char.IsLetter(c) And MyBool = False) Then ' Extract ZAR from "ZAR897.83" string only once
                myStringVal += c
                count = count + 1
            End If
        Next
        If (count > 0) Then 'It already Extracted ZAR so assign MyBool to True
            MyBool = True
        End If
        TotalPrice += Convert.ToDecimal(TotalPriceInStringFormat.ToString())
    Next
    'If you want to return in this format ZAR900.83 Return TotalPriceWithString
    Dim TotalPriceWithString As String = myStringVal + TotalPrice.ToString
    'if you want return 900.83 then TotalPrice
    TotalPrice = Convert.ToDecimal(TotalPriceInStringFormat)

    Return TotalPrice
End Function
```